# How do I make a batch file the default application for a file type

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, file-association

I am trying to associate .svg files with a batch file that runs squiggle from batik.  When I right click on an svg and select `Open With` and `Choose Default Program`, I get the usual window, which lists options that I don't want.  I click on `Browse...` and get a file chooser.

I navigate to the directory with the .bat file, which is visible.  I click on the file and then `Open`.  The file chooser closes, but the batch file does not appear in the `Open With` window.

If I drag the svg file onto the bat file, it works.  How do I make it the default association, so that I can just double click on the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it once via the control panel in Windows.

[image: Control panel file associations]

Comment: This sort of worked.  Initially, it did not recognize the batch file in the same way as going through the `Open With` dialog.  I created a new file called test.bat and copied the contents of batik.bat (my desired file) to that. When I set test.bat as the default application,  it now works.  I'm not sure what the problem with my original file was.  It had been saved with Unix end of lines rather than DOS, but changing that still did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can set it via the command line.

Let's assume your batch file is `c:\temp\myBatch.bat`, and that the .SVG file type is already registered on the system as "svgfile" (you can run `Assoc` from a command prompt to see the current association list to see what type .SVG is associated as).

- Open up an elevated command prompt.
- Type `Ftype svgfile=C:\temp\myBatch.bat %1`
- Open up Explorer and double-click an SVG.
- It should run the batch with the SVG file's path and name fed to it as the first argument.

For more information check out this SU question: [Programatically associate file extensions with application on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/406985/programatically-associate-file-extensions-with-application-on-windows)

Comment: `assoc .svg` says `.svg=XMLSpy.svg`, as does `assoc | find "svg"`. `ftype .svg=<path to batch file> %1` says `File type '.svg' not found or no open commadn associated with it.  Double clicking still uses the old app.

Comment: @TroyDaniels You need to use the name shown by Assoc with FType.  So it appears the command you should use would be `ftype XMLSpy.svg=<path to batch file> %1`.

Comment: hehe a random downvote for a perfectly usable answer.  Gotta love those. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong for me... Maybe it will work for you?

The path to the .bat file was incorrect in the registry.  In my case, it was from an old installation.

1. Run command `regedit`
2. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications` key and find the key named the same as your .bat
3. Once you've found the .bat file key, navigate to the `shell\open\command` subkey.
4. Right-click on the `(Default)` key value, and click **Modify**.
5. Update the command string to point to the correct path and click **OK**.
6. Exit regedit

Try and reassociate the file type as you normally would.

I pulled this information from [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/problems-with-file-association-in-windows-7-64-bit/8a84fcec-22df-4942-8e35-d98dbe96e327?auth=1).