# Windows file associations

Tags: windows-registry, file-association

I'm currently creating a `.vbs` script which is used to change the default program for a specific file extension however I'm not fully certain as to what registry keys/values I need to change. Doing a google search, I came across many posts in which they all mentioned to change values in *HKLM, HKCR and HKCU*, it was a bit confusing because it's all pointing towards different places.

Let's say I want to change the `.txt` file extension so it opens using `CustomProgram.exe`, what are all the Keys/Values and their locations in which I need to change in order for it to work without any sort of error?

Comment: @DavidPostill In that post, the answer, `This is a special registry hive that combines the local user's associations in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes with the system's associations in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes.` but at the top he mentions that all associations are at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. So how do I know which keys/values to edit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programatically associate file extensions with application on Windows](http://superuser.com/q/406985). One of the answers suggests changing value in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`

Comment: Thank you @DavidPostill That was exactly what I needed :)