# Associate a bunch of unassociated file extensions with Notepad++ at once via batch

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, file-association

I've got thousands of files with extensions ".0", ".1", ".2", etc. that I want to associate with Notepad++ (v7.5.8). They currently don't have any file association in Windows (Windows 10). Since they don't have any existing association, the solutions [shown here](https://superuser.com/questions/406985/programatically-associate-file-extensions-with-application-on-windows) aren't working for me.

Also, I'm looking to associate them in Windows, not in the N++ settings, since I access these files from Windows Explorer.

Comment: How many different file extensions are we talking about?  You could associate a single file, export the key, then use Excel to generate the X keys by Cating strings

Answer (score 0):

Much easier than manually associating all the `.#` files, IMO, would be to set up a catch-all edit mode, using regedit:

- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`: Add Key = `Notepad++`, set `(Default)` = `Edit with &Notepad++`
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Notepad++`: Add Key = `command`, set `(Default)` to `"c:\program files (x86)\notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"` -- use the correct path to notepad++.exe for your system, and make sure to have the double-quotes around both the path and the %1, to make sure spaces are handled correctly.

Log off and back on, or reboot.  Now, on any file in explorer, you should be able to right-click, select `Edit with Notepad++`, and voila!

---

### Per-Extension Association (All Users)

Alternately, open up a `cmd.exe` window (run-as-admin if necessary), and run

```
assoc .1=DotNumber
ftype DotNumber="c:\program files (x86)\notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"
for %n in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) DO assoc .%n=DotNumber
```

If you want more `.#` extensions, add them to the for loop.  If you want to set them from a batch file (`setdotn-assoc.bat` or `setdotn-assoc.cmd`) rather than at the `cmd.exe` prompt, need two `%` rather than just one, everything else is the same:

```
assoc .1=DotNumber
ftype DotNumber="c:\program files (x86)\notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"
for %%n in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) DO assoc .%%n=DotNumber
```

---

### Per-Extension Association (Just for Current User)

If you're having problems with permissions on **All Users**, you can try this to do the per-extension association, but just for the current user.

In case you were able to create DotNumber type, `ftype DotNumber=` to remove the existing definition.

Run the following from the command line (shouldn't even need an Administrator command line this time)

```
REG ADD     HKCU\Software\Classes\DotNumber                      /ve /d "DotNumber File" /f
REG ADD     HKCU\Software\Classes\DotNumber\Shell                /ve /d "open" /f
REG ADD     HKCU\Software\Classes\DotNumber\Shell\open           /ve /d "open DotNumber file" /f
REG ADD     HKCU\Software\Classes\DotNumber\Shell\open\command   /ve /d "\"c:\program files (x86)\notepad++\notepad++.exe\" \"^%1\"" /f
FOR %n in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) DO REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\.%n /ve /d "DotNumber" /f
```

And if you want to check if it was written

```
REG QUERY   HKCU\Software\Classes\DotNumber /S
FOR %n in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) DO REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.%n /S
```

Comment: Thank you! The command window method seems to work, except it's a work computer and for each extension it just returns an "Access is denied" error, even when I run it as an admin. Darn.

Comment: Did it create the filetype or not?  `ftype DotNumber` will say "File type 'DotNumber' not found or no open command associated with it" if it wasn't created, otherwise it will show the definition...

Comment: Added a "current-user-only" version in newest edit.  This one shouldn't matter whether or not you have Admin privileges.  At least, it worked for me in a non-admin window.

Comment: The Current User version worked! I don't know much about registry stuff, mind explaining a few things? What does the value of each subkey you create mean? Like, does having HKCU\Software\Classes\DotNumber\Shell have the value "open" mean something in particular? Is "open" a magic word? Is having "Shell" in the registry tree also special?

Comment: The other question I have, is with this setup Windows Explorer shows the type of each of these files as "DotNumber File". Is there a way to make it say "0 File" "1 File" "2 File" etc.? Even if it requires a lot more lines of code with slight changes, that's fine, I can set it up as a batch file

Comment: "shell" as the key is important: this is what tells windows where to look for actions for the filetype. "open" is semi-important: keys under "shell" can have any name, but windows defaults to choosing "open" if there are multiple keys under "shell" and no default is specified. To have a different name for each extension, you would have to have a separate file type key for each -- instead of DotNumber, you would need Dot1, Dot2, ... all with the same info except name; they would then all go inside a multiline-`DO` (see [ss64: `FOR`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) for more `FOR-DO` syntax)

Comment: It's really hard to get the escaping syntax right inside the FOR loop, especially if you're switching between command-line and bat file.  If you only want it for .0 -  .9, I might suggest copy/paste/edit to get each, rather than trying to make it all work in the loop.  The `(x86)` in the NPP path makes it even harder, since that tends to close the DO loop accidentally...

Comment: This has all been really helpful, thank you! And actually my NPP is in the regular program folders file, not x86, so I probably don't have to worry about that DO loop issue. Thanks again!